# Npm commands downloaded but not recognize

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

So I recently update node js pretty much since I was gonna try Angular but now when I try to run any command like `create-react-app appname` I start to get this.

> C:\Users\Mine\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1:
>   This: command not found

now I checked my Environmental variables and on top of my Path folder I have

> C:\Users\Mine\AppData\Roaming\npm which im pretty sure is the correct
>   path.

I've tried to change the path to programfiles\node and it did not work as well.
[image]

Comment: Can you please ensure, ` create-react-app` package is installed in your system?

Comment: I have before the issue I made a react project will state the error to any package I had downloaded in the past.

Comment: Can you check the result `npm ls -g create-react-app` or In your project directory `npm ls create-react-app`? Try to ensure if the modules are installed.

Comment: + create-react-app@3.1.2 updated 1 package in 3.209s     when downloaded than it gives the same error about command not found

Comment: my bad read that wrong C:\Users\Mine\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- create-react-app@3.1.2

Comment: Which version of `node` are you using? Can you please give the output of `node -v`?

Comment: $ node -v
v10.16.3

Comment: It should work properly. Not sure of the problem. I hope someone would help you out. Thank you.

Comment: Might not relevant, but give a try by cleaning the cache. `npm cache clean --force` and
`npm cache verify`

Comment: still nope :( .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you should after update node js uninstall `create-react-app`

```
npm uninstall create-react-app
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm cache clean --force
```

at the next

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Once installation successful, try running

```
npx create-react-app hello-world
```

> **Note**
>
> npx on the first line is not a typo — it’s a package runner tool that
>   comes with npm 5.2+.

Comment: ok so that did the trick for react my other packages like nodemon pretty much say the same thing so i guess uninstall them and redownload them?

Comment: I did a lot of searching when I got into this problem. Finally I cleaned everything up and installed it again. Of course, I reset the system. I also turned off the antivirus and got it running.

Comment: In addition, when updating node js it removes some modules, that need to be reinstalled in the same way above.

Comment: so my packages run it's just they have be used with npx when using npm or just by calling like nodemon will not work, but at least I can get back to coding so im good for now:)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I encountered this issue

> C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1:
> This: command not found

After searching for a solution, I found an alternative approach that resolved the issue for me and worked successfully.

Use: `npx nodemon` if `nodemon app.js` didnt work for you